# How to write unit test for loopback datasource

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I wish to write unit tests for my mongodb datasource in my Loopback 4 project, however I could not find any examples.

Below is my datasource:

```
import {inject, lifeCycleObserver, LifeCycleObserver} from '@loopback/core';
import {juggler} from '@loopback/repository';

const arrayStr: string[] = [];

const config = {
  name: 'mongodb',
  connector: 'mongodb',
  // url: '',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 27017,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  authSource: 'admin',
  database: 'testdb',
  ssl: false, // default to false
  sslValidate: false, // default to false
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  allowExtendedOperators: true,
  sslCA: arrayStr,
};


// Observe application's life cycle to disconnect the datasource when
// application is stopped. This allows the application to be shut down
// gracefully. The `stop()` method is inherited from `juggler.DataSource`.
// Learn more at https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Life-cycle.html
@lifeCycleObserver('datasource')
export class MongodbDataSource extends juggler.DataSource
  implements LifeCycleObserver {
  static dataSourceName = 'mongodb';
  static readonly defaultConfig = config;

  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.config.mongodb', {optional: true})
    dsConfig: object = config,
  ) {
    super(dsConfig);
  }
}
```

I have tried writing a basic constructor test:

```
import {MongodbDataSource} from '../../../datasources';
import {expect} from '@loopback/testlab';

describe('MongoDB Datasource (unit)', () => {
  // we recommend to group tests by method names
  describe('consturctor()', () => {
    it('basic constructor', () => {
      const ds = new MongodbDataSource();
      expect(ds.name).to.equal('mongodb'); // default name
    });
  });
});
```

However, tests will hang/stop and not completed. Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new datasource, the underlying connector (in your case [loopback-connector-mongodb](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb)) will immediately start the process of connecting to the database and will create a connection pool. When your tests finish, the opened connections in this pool are blocking Node.js from exiting.

Personally, I consider this as a bug in LoopBack connector implementations, but that's how things are ‍♂️

You have several options how to address the problem:

1. Tell Mocha to exit the process after all tests finished using Mocha's `exit` flag ([docs](https://mochajs.org/#-exit)). I believe that recently scaffolded LB4 projects should have this flag enabled by default via `.mocharc.json` file.
2. Add an `after` or `afterEach` hook to stop the datasource after the test(s).

   ```
    describe('MongoDB Datasource (unit)', () => {
      let ds: MongodbDataSource;
      // Setup a hook to stop the datasource created by the test
      afterEach(() => ds && ds.stop());

      describe('constructor()', () => {
        it('basic constructor', () => {
          // important: no `const` keyword, use the shared variable
          ds = new MongodbDataSource();
          expect(ds.name).to.equal('mongodb'); // default name
        });
      });
    });
   ```
3. Add `lazyConnect: true` to datasource settings used by your tests. This will prevent the connector from initiating database connections at datasource creation time and defer connecting until a first database request is made.

   ```
    const ds = new MongodbDataSource({
      ...MongodbDataSource.defaultConfig,
      lazyConnect: true,
    });
   ```

These three approaches are independent, you can implement more (or all) of them together.

Comment: thanks @Miroslav option 3 seems to work for me, tried option 2 to cover a default constructor with no parameters but it did not work